# Is there an open source script that replicates Google Finance live graph data?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am trying to create my own graph system on my website, but was wondering if there is already a script out there that emulates google finance's live chart data? I want to be able to plot my own data points on a line graph which gets fed data via a mysql query.

Comment: what do you mean "a script"?

Comment: Try Dojo's charting library or d3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several charting libraries out there, does it have to be open sourced? Most (if not all) offer the ability to pull (and update) from live data [ajax].

- [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)
- [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) ([stock demo](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/))
- [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/)
- [Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/?csw=1) by Google

They don't have to be open-sourced to pull dynamic data and view it on a "live" basis (just configurable to specify a source, or allow post-init data population)